# Too much chat-gpt?

Tags: discussion, chat

I think that too many answers are written in the glib and deathly prose of LLM to keep using this site in goodwill. When someone shows a lack of insight into the question but a verbose and ultimately peculiar knowledge of primary literature, then I cannot really believe that anyone who finds philosophy so easy would deliberately say so much irrelevant nonsense. A simple fix would be demand quotes from 2ndary sources and downvote anything that is flimsily related to the question. Until then, this site is morbid.

Comment: CGPT was released a year ago. How do you account for all the deadly regurgitative answers submitted before?

Comment: Can you provide examples of any such posts?

Comment: There has been plenty of discussion on Meta Stack Exchange about policies regarding AI-generated content.

Comment: Yes, please provide a link to even one example.

Comment: I'm not being disingenuous @ScottRowe  - the last one I tried to point out felt insulted, so I don't know.

Comment: Ok, but you seem upset ('morbid' is a strong word) so I wondered if I could help.

Comment: ah, i often am eh @ScottRowe